# how restore default fraction style on mathpartir package?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to produce a proof tree with different fraction styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \mprset{fraction={===}}
  \inferrule*{
    H_1 \\
    \mprset{fraction={---}}
    \inferrule*{H_0}{H_2}
 }{C}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Here, `\mprset{fraction={---}}` produces a different style as the default one. How to restore the default style in the inner proof tree only?

Comment: Please provide a complete example we can compile.

Comment: Have you tried `\mprset{defaultfraction}`?

Comment: Thanks for adding code, but please don't use `minimal`.

Comment: I get defaultfraction undefined.

Comment: Works for me. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultfraction`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \mprset{fraction={===}}
  \inferrule*{
    H_1 \\
    \mprset{defaultfraction}
    \inferrule*{H_0}{H_2}
 }{C}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: default look for inner inference]

Note that `amsmath` issues warnings with this code about the use of foreign macros for fractions.

Comment: I get  "Package keyval Error: defaultfraction undefined", perhaps I'm using a different mathpartir.sty version? I can't find that option on the current user manual.

Comment: I was using an older version (latest package available from debian repositories). It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Debian tends to have rather outdated packages. Glad you solved it!